# How to migrate tables with consistent foreign keys in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I have csv file with data

```
name, state
```

.

I want to put those data to tables:

```
Table1{id[PK], name}
State{table1_id[FK], state}.
```

Main problem here is to how store newly created Table1 id and use it during inserting to State table
How to do this with pentaho?

Answer (score 2):

For Table1 (in your example it is dimension) use 'Combination lookup/update' from 'Data Warehouse' tab:

- Dimension field=name
- Field in stream=name
- Technical key field=id

Connect 'Combination lookup/update' to 'Insert / Update'. Use 'Insert / Update' for State table (in your example it is fact table)

- the key(s) to look up the value(s): state=state, table1_id=id;
- Update fields: state=state, Table1_id=id, all with Y flag for update

'Combination lookup/update' check if given Field exists in Dimension table if yes then you have id from database if not then new value will be inserted and new key returned.

Regards
Mateusz